# Can iPod touch 5th gen use older versions of apps?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, software-update

I know it's possible to drag and drop an older version of an app from apps you downloaded in your iTunes onto your iPod but will this work with the new iPod touch 5th gen? I was gonna get the iPod touch 5 but there are some apps that have updates and I don't like the updates at all. I have a 3rd gen iPod touch and I put an older version of Textfree/Pinger on it and it works fine but it has an update I don't want and I would like to have the older version on my new iPod but will it work?

Can some one try it and drag and drop an older version of an app onto their iPod 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all updates to iOS so far have been backwards-compatible with older versions of apps, so the apps should work fine.